# How to show widget of woocommerce into sidebar of page

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

Hello I am working with woocommerce plugin and I am using widget for sidebar.

But using widget.widget is not showing on the sidebar they are showing below to

the product how to show widget on sidebar is it possible using css or other

solution for that.

Here is [link](http://thenickgaryfoundation.com/shop/)

Comment: as per my understand both class 'leftPanel' and 'rightPanel' under same div of class 'mainclass' and then possible add css to leftPanel float: left; and width: 70%; or vary css accordingly.

Comment: actually i add these class in archive_product and  use left and rightpanel class in mainclass but on browser it is not geting

Answer (score 0):

- Please refer the below snapshot we made changes in your structured using browser console.
- https://www.screencast.com/t/NprV333xgq
- https://www.screencast.com/t/7Xt16uPI65
- If you have added your sidebar data under the rightPanle div still data are not arrive correct means that some where have div closing issue.
- Would you please check your structured all div are properly close.